# Class variables lifetime in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class variable named fields which is initiated like this:

```
@@fields ||= JSON.parse(@client.run_request(@request_path, 'get', params))["data"]
```

after the first time the method is called, in another rails request, `@@fields` still holds the

When does this value expire?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using class variable in here instead of instance variable?

Answer (score 2):

class variables do not expire, you can always access them through the class, instance variables can be accessed as long as the object lives, have a read here

http://thoughts.codegram.com/understanding-class-instance-variables-in-ruby/